# How to do modeling if we have multiple relationship between fact and dimension table

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have got one table contains employee details and another one with employee document details.
Employee document table is mainly used to tag document expiry of the employee.
The situation is that , in employee document table we have got visa id, licence id, insurance id which are all tagged to employee id in employee table.
That means if visa id is 15 it refers to employee id 15 and I have to extract details of these particular employees from employee table.
Currently used USERELATIONSHIP function in DAX and i'm not still getting how to achieve it. Does the modeling which is wrong ? I'm new to these .

[image: You can find table image here]

Comment: Your current data model is incorrect. You need to restructure the data into a proper star schema: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/guidance/star-schema
For example, you might have Dimension "Employee", another Dimension "Document" (which lists various document types), and a Fact table "Employee Documents" that combines Employees and Documents. These tables will have only one connection, from Dimension to Fact.

Comment: Hai thanks for your feedback. yeah, i do have one more table with document type . My concern was like fact table "employee document" have around 4-5 columns which have relation ship with dimension table "employee" with respective employee id. In above image you can see "emirates id" in "employee document" links to the "id" in "employee" table. Similarly, "driving_employee_id" links with "id" in "employee" table and three more columns like that. And i have to fetch "name" from "employee" table for respective "emirates_employee_id","driving_employee_id" .......

Comment: How i can achieve that should i need to break down any table ?

Comment: Hey, I think I have got the solution. If i combine all those "emirates_employee_id" , "driving_employye_id" , "insurance_employee_id" to one column the things will get sort it out.